# Fixing independent variables in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Let's say we have 3 independent variables x1, x2, x3. If we fix any value for variables x1 and x2, but increase the value of variable x3 by 1, how much would the predicted (dependent) variable y increase?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, see [our policy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Depends on the model formula. Are there any interactions in there? If not, I would say, by the coefficient of this variable.